# Click on LIKE and sumbit info at the same time

Tags: facebook-like, form-submit

I'm working on a sales promotion for a client. They would like this promotion to revolve around "Liking" their product on FB. I need to be able to add a LIKE button on the their Website (not a FB page) have a person click "LIKE" and then submit their email address to receive a coupon. So my question is : Is there a way to click on LIKE and submit an email address at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - you can not do this.  In order to retrieve a users email address you must first authenticate that user to use your application and then request the `email` permission - that brings me to my second point - you have to have an application in order to request this information.

Comment: Thank you for the speedy answer. Back to the drawing board I go :/

Comment: No problem! You can however capture a "like" action and perform your own actions afterwards - for example prompting the user to enter his/her email **if** they would like to receive emails from you.
If this answer assisted you please mark it as "answered" :)

Comment: Oh this might work! How do I go about doing this or where should I go to read more about figuring out how to do it?

Comment: It involves using the javascript callbacks that facebook provides after actions such as posting/logging in or out.  It is not complicated but that said it is not really a question that i can answer in this forum.  You'll need a band of code monkeys/programmers to help you write some code and this is a programmers QA site.